# what is the event for vertical swipe

Tags: jquery-mobile

I looked at jquerymobile documentation and saw:
event for `swipe`, `swipeleft` and `swiperight`

is there a **swipevertical**  event or similar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately swipeup and swipedown don't exist in jQuery mobile and they are not planed for version 1.3. There is an 3rd party plugin here: http://developingwithstyle.blogspot.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-swipe-up-down-left-right.html. Use them like you would use normal events: **swipedown** and **swipeup**.

You can also use this plugin if you need this implementation: http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library. It also works on Android devices. This is a worst case scenario solution because unlike official event there ones don't work on desktop browsers.

Here's an working example, test it on mobile devices only: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/WYnnk/

```
    $("#wrapper").touchwipe({
         wipeLeft: function() { 
             $("#carousel").trigger("next", 1);
         },
         wipeRight: function() { 
             $("#carousel").trigger("next", 1);        
         },
         min_move_x: 20,
         min_move_y: 20,
         preventDefaultEvents: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding the following code to a [pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/) handler, I was able to simulate a **pull to refresh** feature on the header of my page...

```
  // Set aside the thresholds so they can be reset later.
  var _scrollSupressionThreshold = $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold;
  var _horizontalDistanceThreshold = $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold;
  var _verticalDistanceThreshold = $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold;

  // Adjust the thresholds for a vertical swipe.
  $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = 5;
  $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 1;
  $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold = 128;

  // Listen for the swipe event...
  $('#my_jqm_page div[data-role="header"]').on("swipe", function() {

    // Reset thresholds.
    $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = _scrollSupressionThreshold;
    $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = _horizontalDistanceThreshold;
    $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold = _verticalDistanceThreshold;

    // Take action...
    console.log('Vertical swipe!');

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

i think there's a vmouseover, which is a virtual mouseover

Comment: aren't you confusing between vertical and virtual?

Comment: no it's a virtual vertical mouse over i think - both! that's my understanding